# Align unknown height image along bottom of RelativeLayout

Tags: android, image, layout

I need to have a screen with an image laid out along the bottom of the screen.  The image itself is fixed (from resources).  It's quite large and is scaled down to the width of each device. I tried to use simple `layout_alignParentBottom`, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LayoutLoading"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/startup" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/loading" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Yes, this didn't work.  Unless I specify exact height of the image (in place of `wrap_content`), the `ImageView` is not aligned at the bottom.  Most likely this is due to the fact that the actual image is higher than the screen size and becomes "shorter" only after scaled down to the width of the screen.

So, the question is how do I get the `ImageView` to stay at the bottom of the screen regardless of the size of the device?

Comment: Side-note: You can remove ``android:orientation="vertical"`` as it seems to be a leftover from a ``LinearLayout`` approach. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add to your imageview in xml `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`